# Losing Rows - Export Shape not creating 1 to 1 duplicate

Tags: qgis, arcmap

I have a shape file with 1,900,589 rows associated to it. I attempt to make a copy of it by exporting it, and the total row count drops significantly. I just did a generic scroll through the data, by doing a ctrl-shft-end, and it looks like all the records are legit.

-RAM usage on my PC never gets above 50% during the export. (16gb ram on my machine)

---

In ArcMap 10.7, after the export, the row count drops down to 1,600,260

-The method I'm using to export, is right clicking on the file in the table of contents, Data, Export Data..., Exporting All Features, changing the file name.

-The original file size is 2.07GB

-Post export file size is 2.06GB (Losing 300k rows seems like it should have had a more significant effect on this file size?)

---

In QGIS 3.24.3, after the export, the row count drops down to 1,299,930

-Weird thing about QGIS, when I open the table, at the top, it says Features total 1,900,589, Filtered 1,299,930. I have nothing filtered...

I also read about a possible bug where you had to change the "Show All Features button" to "Show Features Visible On Map". (Which still showed 1,299,930 records)

---

I'm going to try splitting this file down into a few smaller chunks, and see if it behaves any differently, but that is not going to stop the pain of me not know why it's doing this.

Comment: Shape file have a (theoretical : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312739/why-are-shapefiles-limited-to-2gb-in-size) size limit of 2gb, you seem to be right on it so your problem may come from that. Did you try to export to a more suitable format for large file ?

Comment: That, at least makes sense. I can live with too beaucoup. Thank you! I suspect this is probably the issue. I reloaded the original CSV into QGIS, and it actually has 2,501,248 rows. Suspecting I lost some when converting it from csv to shape in ArcMap. QGIS seems to be handling it fine now that I'm avoiding the .shp.

Thanks again